# Alarm clock on iOS with background initiated audio

Tags: ios, background

Is there any way to create a alarm clock on iOS that can play audio (>30s) at specified time?

Here is what I tried:

1) Local notification: too short. Only 30s

2) Background audio: not allowed to start playing at background

3) Play a silent audio and blocking the app from becoming suspended: Doable, but possible rejection from Apple.

Any other ideas?

Comment: see this demo ... https://github.com/Bizzl3/Alarm-Clock-iOS

Comment: Thanks Kirit. I took a brief look and run. I can only find local notification is used as way of playing timed audio. Let me know if I am wrong.